# Which version of acceleo is been used in screencasts?

Tags: acceleo

Can anyone please tell me which version of acceleo is been used in screencasts of acceleo website? Because currently I am using acceleo 2.7 and I am trying to do the same thing but I don't get the expected results!

---

Edit:

I am new to Acceleo and I was trying to learn from the tutorials, I downloaded topcased integrated into eclipse helios 'Topcased-RCP-win32-4.3.0.zip' from this link

http://www.topcased.org/index.php?idd_projet_pere=52&Itemid=60

and it is associated with acceleo 2.7, apparently the topcased is working because I can create the diagrams with no problem but when I create a new module launcher for hibernate and launch it, according to this screen cast

http://acceleo.org/screencast.phpwidth=1024&height=788&swf=modules/pages/jee/images/screencast/GenerationBDAcceleo&lang=en

it should generate the hbm.xml file and the sql files but the only thing I get is a 'src' folder and some other subfolders in it has been generated with no code!

Answer (score 0):

Daniel,

Which screencasts are you talking about? The official Acceleo website is now [hosted on Eclipse](http://www.eclipse.org/acceleo/). Are you talking about the screencasts that can be found on its [documentation page](http://www.eclipse.org/acceleo/documentation/)? Or about those that can be located through the [Eclipse wiki](http://wiki.eclipse.org/Acceleo/Videos)? These are all for the current version of Acceleo, i.e the versions 3.*.

However if you are talking about the [acceleo.org](http://www.acceleo.org/pages/home) website, as you can see from its homepage, it is a website for the maintenance release (the versions 2.*). If you are using Acceleo 2.7, this is the website where you can locate accurate screencasts. We do not encourage users to start using Acceleo with this version though, and we recommend using the Acceleo 3.x stream instead.

Comment: Kellindil, I meant these screencasts http://acceleo.org/screencast.php?width=1024&height=788&swf=modules/pages/jee/images/screencast/GenerationBDAcceleo&lang=en

Comment: As mentionned above, this is a screencast for Acceleo 2.*; most likely created with Acceleo 2.6. Following it to the letter should net you the same result with Acceleo 2.7 and Acceleo 2.8

Comment: Well I am doing the exact same thing and I am following it step by step but still doesn't generate the code for me as in the screecasts!!!! I don't know if it is the problem with the acceleo or what??!!!!

Comment: Daniel, first things first, if you don't try and explain what's going on, we can in no way help you. All development now takes place on Acceleo 3 and Acceleo 2 is only maintained for bug fixes. The official support channel for Acceleo 2 remains the forum on the maintenance site : http://www.acceleo.org/forum/; or you could try to contact directly Obeo (the creators of Acceleo) : http://obeo.fr/

Comment: Kellindil, the explanation of my problem is been added to my question.

Comment: Daniel, I myself do not know the answer to this, and you'll have to wait for the support team of Acceleo 2 to take a look at this. They should do when they are back.